# Why is playing to the spirit of the game considered so important in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

It's something I've always wondered about. I, myself, do not like to see players and sometimes even whole teams use the Laws to their advantage. In other sports, notably football (soccer), playing by the spirit of the game is much less of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cricket was a game formed in England by the gentry. The English have a long and strong historic tradition of *being the better man*.

The ethos of playing the game for the game's own sake was reflected in many sports of English origin, notably football and field hockey - early rule books of these sports exhorted players to adhere to the spirit of the game and of fair play as late as the 1920s and 1930s.

Cricket is not exceptional in this regard in the modern era of sports either. The Pyeongchang Winter Olympics 2018 were marred by controversy in its curling competition after one team chose an entirely valid and legitimate penalty instead of a less useful one, solely because this choice was so far outside the expectations of politeness and good manners within the game. To a lesser extent this politeness exists in golf, related by culture to both curling and cricket, and reflects a similar cultural pride in "doing one's best regardless of the result". Ultimate (frisbee) requires adherence to the spirit of  the game for a game to even proceed, in the deliberate absence of referees and umpires to control violations of rule.

In summary, cricket (and other sports with such an attitude) treat it as important because they have always treated it as important, and the basis of this importance stems from wider cultural attitudes.

Comment: This is pretty much my view on the subject: cricket is a gentleman's game, and gentlemen play the game a certain way... but I'd love to see some supporting references.

Answer (score 0):

Its viewed by the organisations in charge that the spirit of the game is an important part of history and what makes Cricket different and so players, officials and organisers are encouraged to support the spirit of the game to keep crickets special place in society.